# Output the maximum score

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a following list of teams with their score:

```
List<String> teams = Arrays.asList("Dortmund 8", "Bayern 10", "Madrid 9", "Bayern 2", "Dortmund 4");
```

I need to output the team who got maximum score. If the scores are equal, output the team who got it first. In my example Dortmund and Bayern has equal score, but Bayern got it first. So the output is Bayern. Here is what I have for now:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : teams) {
        String[] rec = s.split(" ");
        int val = Integer.parseInt(rec[1]);
        map.put(rec[0], map.get(rec[0])==null ? val : map.get(rec[0]) + val);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

The code just sum the scores of each team and save it on map. I could not change the way I need.

Comment: First of all you'll need to use something other than `HashMap` that preserves the order of insertion so that you can figure out the ties.

Comment: @rdas I thought that Hashmap is good for having separately the teams and teir score

Comment: the order of insertion comes naturally from the list. The hashmap is just a store where he adds the goals

Comment: @AlexBlack and you thought well : )

Comment: You covered this issue in your comments and it was addressed in the answer(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int max = 0;
String bestTeam="";

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String s : teams) 
{
    String[] rec = s.split(" ");
    int val = Integer.parseInt(rec[1]);
    int sum = map.get(rec[0])==null ? val : map.get(rec[0]) + val;
    map.put(rec[0], sum);
    if (sum>max) {
        max = sum;
        bestTeam = rec[0];
    }  
}

System.out.println("Max score winner team :" + bestTeam + "-["+max+"] goals");
```

- Other approaches just selected the max entry. The streams approaches written here  by **[Alex Rudenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66332573/2148953)** and [**Nikolas Charalambidis**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66331389/2148953) are the perfect example of how streams should handle this scenarios. Related to this, the use of a map, which solely is used to save the total scored goals for each team. The sorting is implicit in an arraylist iteration. The hashmap wasn't never involved in any type of sorting.

  *`Dortmund 11", "Bayern 10", "Madrid 9", "Bayern 2", "Bayern 4"`*

  The winner of this list **is not Dortmund, but Bayern**.
- The best team is the one which scores the most goals, after adding all the entries. If two teams share the same max score, the winner is the team that first reach to that max.

  *`Dortmund 15", "Bayern 2", "Dortmund 4", "Bayern 20", "Dortmund 3"`*

  Both teams share the same max score: 22. The winner is **Bayern**, as it reached the max score first.
- The logic is as simple as comparing the current maximum score with the current sum. The condition is **`sum>max`** and not **`sum>=max`** to guarantee that the first team who reached to that max is the winner.

---

***Tested, working:***

**`Max score winner team :Bayern-[12]`**

[image]

Comment: `HashMap` does not preserve insertion order. So on duplicate score you might not have right answer.

Comment: The hashmap is not used at all  to get the order. The iteration already retrieves the teams ordered. The hashmap is used for just one reason: store the goals. The order in `String s : teams` is guaranteed. Test it.

Comment: You don't have to care wether the goals are stored here or there in the hashmap: the key is that the team retrieved from `String s : teams` yes is ordered. So the first one that gets the max, regardless the duplicates and regardless where the map stored each entry,is the winner

Comment: @aran I think you can simply this two lines     int sum = map.get(rec[0])==null ? val : map.get(rec[0]) + val;
    map.put(rec[0], sum); into             int sum = map.compute(rec[0], (k, v) -> v == null ? val : v + val);

Comment: @aran IMO this version is more readable than the version with streams

Comment: I found today that stream solution does not guarantee the order, e.g. if replace `Dortmund` with `AEK`, `AEK` will be selected first.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way using Stream API, Regex (see demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1G4FoN/2)) and the classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

> ```
> ([A-Za-z ]+) (\d+)
> ```

Remember in Java the Regex must be double-escaped (`\d` -> `\\d`):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z ]+)(\\d+)");

Optional<String> result = teams.stream()
    .map(pattern::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::find)
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                matcher -> matcher.group(1),
                LinkedHashMap::new,
                Collectors.summingInt(m -> Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)))),
            m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Entry::getValue))
                    .map(e -> e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue())));
```

The `Matcher` has the advantage it holds the original String (`group()`) and the captured groups (`group(int)`). After calling `Matcher#find` you are able to work with the captured groups. Get a group the number is in and use it for the summing into downstream of `groupingBy` collector to get a `Map<String, Integer>` with the name of the team as a key and their total sum of the score as a value. The map supplier `LinkedHashMap::new` assures an ordered map.

The subsequent `Collectors.collectingAndThen` takes the entries and finds the one having the highest score. The whole Stream results in `Optional<String>` as long as the processing is ready to return an empty `Optional` in case of the input list is empty.

**An important note:** Consider using rather a class for such construct (with `String name` and `int score`). The further operations would be the way easier.

Comment: I appreciate a lot this, really. You noticed a mistake and you invested some of your time for this. Respect to you @Nikolas

Answer (score 1):

A stream-based solution should use `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.summingInt` to calculate the total goals/points into a map and then get maximum value out of its entries:

```java
teams.stream()
     .map(s -> s.split(" ")) // Stream<String[]>
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], 
              Collectors.summingInt(arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[1])))) // Map<String, Integer>
     .entrySet().stream()
     .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
     .ifPresentOrElse(e -> System.out.printf("Stream: %s - %d goals%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()),
                      () -> System.out.println("No team found"));
```

Output:

```
Stream: Bayern - 12 goals
```

**Update**
However, this solution does not guarantee that the team which scored the maximum goals the earliest will be selected as a winner.

For `List<String> teams = Arrays.asList("AEK 8", "Bayern 10", "Madrid 9", "Bayern 2", "AEK 4");` the result is `AEK`.

---

Similar loop-based version could be using `Map::merge` to calculate the total value of goals/points:

```java
Map<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<>();
String maxTeam = null;
int max = 0;
for (String record : teams) {
    String[] r = record.split(" ");
    if (max < totals.merge(r[0], Integer.parseInt(r[1]), Integer::sum)) {
        maxTeam = r[0];
        max = totals.get(maxTeam);
    }
}
System.out.printf("Loop: %s - %d goals%n", maxTeam, max);
```

Output:

```
Loop: Bayern - 12 goals
```